# How to Display output of php file though pure javascript ?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple PHP file hello.php which display 'hello world' message like this

```
<?php
       echo "Hello world!";
?>
```

I want to store this message in javascript variable. how i can do this ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var result= // output returned from hello.php
   alert(result);
</script>
```

Comment: ajax. Are you using any js library like jquery?

Comment: Is the script block ina a php page as well? then `var result = <?php include('hello.php'); ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the downvote but here is the answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var result = '<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>';
   alert(result);
</script>
```

This will store **Hello World!** in the javascript variable called `result`

Please take note of the single quotes `'` before and after the php tags, if you don't use these it will cause a parse error in javascript.

Comment: Well i guess this answer is correct as it has been accepted, but the question clearly suggests the js and php are in different files. Downvotes for the question are probably due to the complete lack of research on OPs part